# Matrix indexing using vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I'm a beginner in MATLAB so this question might be trivial.

Suppose `x=[1 2 3 4 5]` and `y=[3 4 2 5 1]` and `img = zeros(5,5)`. I want to set `img(1,3),(2,4),(3,2),(4,5),(5,1)` to 1. How do I do this? When I simply try `img(x,y)`, it takes all the combinations of indices like `(1,3),(1,4),(1,2)` etc. which is not what I want.

Comment: Take a look at [`sub2ind`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) , [`sparse`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have experienced, MATLABs indexing doesn't work that way. To get a feeling for the ways indexing works in MATLAB, please have a look at [this nice article](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) from Mathworks.

Now how to tackle your problem: The solution is to use *linear* indexing. You can always index a 2-dimensional matrix either by `(i,j)` or with a linear index `k` which increases column-wise. You can convert between matrix-indexes and linear indexes using the `sub2ind` function. To get the correct indexes for your questions, use

```
img = zeros(5,5)
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [3 4 2 5 1];

ind = sub2ind(size(img),x,y);
img(ind) = 1;
```